# Use Mule standalone with Runtime Manager

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb, anypoint-platform

If I run Mule standalone, all documentation is asking me to register the standalone instance with Mule Runtime Manager (which is by default Cloud but I assume it can be on a private cloud too). This launches an agent that registers the Mule instance with Cloud based Runtime manager.

Questions are:

1. Is it possible to run Mule standalone without registering with
   Runtime manager?
2. If yes, are there any monitoring and health check
   capabilities available directly from Mule standalone instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. If you don't register it with Anypoint Runtime Manager, then it just runs standalone.
2. The only health check is one built in that pings the process to see if it is unresponsive and restarts the Mule process. There are no monitoring capabilities in standalone mode. Those are provided by Anypoint Platform.

Note that Runtime Manager can indeed be run in a private cloud but only as part of an [Anypoint Platform Private Cloud Edition](https://docs.mulesoft.com/private-cloud/latest/) (PCE) installation.

Answer (score 0):

We run standalone instances that we used to connect to MMC, even without support for a while. Our sales rep urged us to switch to Anypoint Runtime Mgr(ARM) and with his assistance we did so, including help with logins for our staff mbrs needing it. That means we connected/logged in to Mulesoft site remotely via browser, connecting to anypoint.mulesoft.com plus some more URL detail that i won't reveal herein. We then identified our local standalone test Mule Server (our standalones are all Windows Servers) within ARM to monitor(which provides stopped/started failed/successful statuses) at deployment time and during regular operations of our apps from our local filesystems to the standalone.-------------
There are many other benefits to ARM which i won't go into at this time, but it(ARM) works well, has been reliable and gives us both application and server statuses on demand. Alerts can be set as well but we haven't set any of those up as yet. In ARM we are running Gateway version:3.9.3 Agent version:1.14.2.
Please note that we are remaining at Mule V3.9.x for the time being. (No time for app flow conversion to Dataweave in 4.x.x)
Hope this helps some to convince you of ARM usefulness, especially as versus to staff server access for the migration/depoyment process, even in test.
--MPC